# Error retrieving AppStore application's reviews using app-store-scraper?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, app-store

Here is what I have tried and it didn't work:

First `pip3 install app-store-scraper` and then:

```
from app_store_scraper import AppStore
from pprint import pprint

appstore_app = AppStore(country="us", app_name="yazio-fasting-food-tracker", app_id=946099227)
appstore_app.review()

pprint(appstore_app.reviews)
pprint(appstore_app.reviews_count)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    159             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 160                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    161             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     60 
---> 61     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     62         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    747     addrlist = []
--> 748     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    749         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    676                 headers=headers,
--> 677                 chunked=chunked,
    678             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    975         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 976             conn.connect()
    977 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    307         # Add certificate verification
--> 308         conn = self._new_conn()
    309         hostname = self.host

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    171             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 172                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
    173             )

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1a3eb18390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    724             retries = retries.increment(
--> 725                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    726             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    438         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 439             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    440 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apps.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /us/app/yazio-fasting-food-tracker/id946099227 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1a3eb18390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c7ec3a01ece6> in <module>
      2 from pprint import pprint
      3 
----> 4 appstore_app = AppStore(country="us", app_name="yazio-fasting-food-tracker", app_id=946099227)
      5 appstore_app.review(how_many=1000)
      6 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/app_store_scraper/app_store.py in __init__(self, country, app_name, app_id, log_format, log_level, log_interval)
     27             log_format=log_format,
     28             log_level=log_level,
---> 29             log_interval=log_interval,
     30         )
     31 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/app_store_scraper/base.py in __init__(self, country, app_name, app_id, log_format, log_level, log_interval)
     62         self._request_headers = {
     63             "Accept": "application/json",
---> 64             "Authorization": self._token(),
     65             "Connection": "keep-alive",
     66             "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/app_store_scraper/base.py in _token(self)
    126 
    127     def _token(self):
--> 128         self._get(self.url)
    129         tags = self._response.text.splitlines()
    130         for tag in tags:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/app_store_scraper/base.py in _get(self, url, headers, params, total, backoff_factor, status_forcelist)
    123             s.mount(self._base_request_url, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    124             logger.debug(f"Making a GET request: {url}")
--> 125             self._response = s.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    126 
    127     def _token(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    541 
    542         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 543         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    544 
    545     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apps.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /us/app/yazio-fasting-food-tracker/id946099227 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1a3eb18390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Please advise how to deal with this error, or maybe there is another way to parse AppStore reviews.

Comment: Double check your Internet connection. There's nothing wrong with your code. It works for me as is.

Comment: @baduker getting this:

```2020-10-02 18:01:47,362 [INFO] Base - Initialised: AppStore('us', 'yazio-fasting-food-tracker', 946099227)
2020-10-02 18:01:47,365 [INFO] Base - Ready to fetch reviews from: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/yazio-fasting-food-tracker/id946099227
2020-10-02 18:01:47,684 [ERROR] Base - Something went wrong: 'data'
2020-10-02 18:01:47,686 [INFO] Base - [id:946099227] Fetched 0 reviews (0 fetched in total)```

Comment: Are you executing the code you have in the question? There's no `data` in the code you have here. Also, have you tried scraping the AppStore before? Maybe your IP gets banned?

Comment: This is what I get `2020-10-02 17:05:32,555 [INFO] Base - Initialised: AppStore('us', 'yazio-fasting-food-tracker', 946099227)
2020-10-02 17:05:32,555 [INFO] Base - Ready to fetch reviews from: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/yazio-fasting-food-tracker/id946099227
2020-10-02 17:05:34,891 [INFO] Base - [id:946099227] Fetched 534 reviews (534 fetched in total)`

Comment: Wow, that isn't what I see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222410/discussion-between-baduker-and-steves).

Comment: @baduker I am waiting you in the chat

Answer (score 2):

I've played a bit with this API wrapper and it seems the results you get back are either IP based or there's something odd about the wrapper.

Anyhow, here's the code I got 533 reviews. The entire dump is on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8vYa3PV1).

```
import json

from app_store_scraper import AppStore
from pprint import pprint

appstore_app = AppStore(country="us", app_name="yazio-fasting-food-tracker", app_id=946099227)
appstore_app.review()

reviews = appstore_app.reviews
pprint(appstore_app.reviews_count)

for review in reviews:
    review['date'] = review['date'].isoformat()


with open("data_dump.json", "w") as dd:
    json.dump(reviews, dd, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

This outputs:

```
2020-10-03 18:28:35,477 [INFO] Base - Initialised: AppStore('us', 'yazio-fasting-food-tracker', 946099227)
2020-10-03 18:28:35,477 [INFO] Base - Ready to fetch reviews from: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/yazio-fasting-food-tracker/id946099227
2020-10-03 18:28:40,681 [INFO] Base - [id:946099227] Fetched 260 reviews (260 fetched in total)
533
2020-10-03 18:28:46,415 [INFO] Base - [id:946099227] Fetched 533 reviews (533 fetched in total)
```